# Python OverflowError for Newton-Raphson root finding method

Tags: python, overflow, root

```
x=float(raw_input('Enter a number to show its square root'))
precise = 0.01
g=x/2.0
while abs(g**2-x)>=precise:
   g=g-(g**2-x)/2*g
print g
```

This is a python code based on Newton-Raphson Root Finding method. When I run this in Canopy, I can find root of 1. But when i input 25 to find the root, it says `OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')`  pointing out to the `while abs(g**2-x)>=precise:`  line. Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about your algorithm. Move your `print g` inside your while loop and you will see that `g` is getting really really big, really fast. Then you are trying to square it. Is your denominator supposed to be `2*g`? If so then you should  put parenthesis around it like `(2*g)`, because you are dividing by `2` and then multiplying by `g`. Probably not what you wanted to do.

Comment: You rock man... Adding the paranthesis seems to do the trick! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When using the Newton-Raphson method for root finding, I always find it usefull to use my standard code for this algorithm and specify it where necessary. Maybe you will find this usefull as well.

```
ftn1 <- function(x){
  fx <- log(x) -exp(-x)
  dfx <- 1/x + exp(-x)
  return(c(fx,dfx))
}


newtonraphson <- function(ftn, x0, tol = 1e-9, max.iter = 100) {

  x <- x0
  fx <- ftn(x)
  iter <- 0
  while ((abs(fx[1]) > tol) && (iter < max.iter)) {
    x <- x - fx[1]/fx[2]
    fx <- ftn(x)
    iter <- iter + 1
    cat("At iteration", iter, "value of x is:", x, "\n")
  }
  if (abs(fx[1]) > tol) {
    cat("Algorithm failed to converge\n")
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    cat("Algorithm converged\n")
    return(x)
  }
}
newtonraphson(ftn1, 0.1)
```